# Can we alter the Views present in the layout xml file for the Views present inside the include tag.

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to re-use an already created layout xml file in another xml file by means of

My current XML file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/insertTask"
        layout="@layout/activity_edit_screen">

    </include>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout file activity_edit_screen has a button named "Update", I want to change that button to "Add". That is the only change between the two xml files. How can I achevie this? I am trying to re-use one xml in another. Please provide suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change it at runtime. See the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rename the button in code behind.

```
Button button=(Button)findViewByID(R.id.button1);
            button.setText("Add");
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. This worked. Since this is the first time I am encountering this, I did not think in that direction. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the button text in onCreate() after initializing view.

```
Button sample_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sample_btn);
sample_btn.setText("Add")
```

;

Comment: Yes did the same. thanks. Sorry I cannot accept two answers I feel. Can I?